# Setting TERM variable for Emacs shell

Tags: emacs, environment-variables

Is it possible to set the TERM environment variable for Emacs shell to some other value than "dumb"? In order to make TRAMP work I'm adjusting some parts of .bashrc on remote machines according to $TERM == "dumb" condition but for the shell I'd like these ignored (opposite approach - setting the TERM for TRUMP - would also be applicable).

Comment: You can test the `INSIDE_EMACS` environment variable without messing with `TERM` (which would seem like a potentially hazardous thing to do).

Comment: The point of `TERM` is to tell programs what kind of terminal they're running in, so they can decide how to control the terminal.  `TERM=dumb` is correct because `shell` isn't a terminal.  If you set `TERM` to something else, you'll trick any programs that look at that variable, but the results will be wrong because the terminal itself won't behave as indicated.

Comment: Thanks, think I've got the idea now, guess it's just better to use Emacs `term` if I want something non-dumb then.

Answer (score 12):

Let me give your answer in two parts: first, one that technically answers your question but isn't very useful, and second, one that probably answers your needs even though it takes a different tack to get there.

### Setting `TERM` in the shell

When starting `shell-mode` with `M-x shell`, Emacs starts the shell you want (usually the same as your login shell, but this can be changed if you really want to) and then sources a file, if it exists, based on the shell's name. The places it looks are

1. `~/.emacs_$SHELLNAME`
2. `~/.emacs.d/init_${SHELLNAME}.sh`

In this file you can set `TERM`. For instance, if you use *zsh*, and create the file

```bash
# ~/.emacs_zsh or ~/.emacs.d/init_zsh.sh
export TERM=emacs
```

then you'll get what you asked for: shells started with `M-x shell` will have the `TERM` set to `emacs` instead of `dumb`.

While this technically answers your question, though, it's not particularly useful—if you try it, here's what you'll get when you start a shell:

```
zsh: can't find terminal definition for emacs
$ echo $TERM
emacs
$
```

The issue here is that `shell-mode` doesn't implement any terminal emulation. In other words, `dumb` *is* exactly the right `TERM` value to use.

(Note there *are* modes that emulate terminals—see, for instance, `M-x ansi-term`—and they set `TERM=eterm-color` or similar, but they're designed to let you use Emacs as an xterm replacement for visual-mode shell commands, whereas `M-x shell` is designed to let you *run* shell commands while still interacting with the input and output in an Emacs-y way.)

When you choose a `TERM` value that isn't supported by *termcap,* you'll get the above error and some programs may get confused about what's happening (and some will refuse to run at all). If you select a full-featured `TERM` value like `xterm` instead, you'll get "line-noise" characters as the programs attempt to send formatting codes to a terminal emulator that isn't there.

You could probably get away with finding some termcap that was limited enough in capabilities that it won't bother you with noise too much, but if this is just to let you differentiate Emacs interactive shells from either Emacs non-interactive shells or non-Emacs interactive shells, there's a better choice.

This choice, in fact, *isn't even sufficient.* That's because this special shell script is loaded by *both* `shell-mode` *and* by TRAMP, so the above still wouldn't let you differentiate the two—you'd just get `emacs` in both cases instead of `dumb`!

So this is where the better choice comes in:

## Using the `INSIDE_EMACS` environment variable

While, as you noted, the interactive shell and TRAMP both set `TERM` to `dumb` by default, they also set an environment variable `INSIDE_EMACS`.

Its existence (or not) alone is useful for your shell startup scripts, but its power for your use case lies in its value—which, for interactive (`M-x shell`) use, is something like `25.2.2,comint`, but for TRAMP is `25.2.2,tramp`.

So, to check for the three cases, here's what you can do (and what I personally have done myself in my *~/.zshrc* for many years):

```bash
# Setup for all shells--Emacs or not, interactive or not, goes
# here
PATH=...
source $my_functions_file

# Now dumb terminals
if [[ "${TERM}" == "dumb" ]]; then
  # Here put anything you want to run in any dumb terminal,
  # even outside Emacs.
  PATH=...
  alias lsF='ls -F'
  etc

  # Now, just configs for shells inside Emacs
  case ${INSIDE_EMACS/*,/} in
    (comint)
      do_comint_stuff
      ;;
    (tramp)
      do_tramp_stuff
      ;;
    (term*)
      # For M-x ansi-term, etc., you get a value like
      #   25.2.2,term:0.96, but those shouldn't coincide with
      #   TERM being `dumb`, so warn....
      echo "We somehow have a dumb Emacs terminal ${INSIDE_EMACS/*,/}" >&2
      ;;
    ("")
      # Empty means we're $TERM==dumb but not in Emacs, do nothing
      ;;
    (*)
      # We shouldn't get here, so write a warning so we can
      # figure out how else Emacs might be running a shell,
      # but send it to stderr so that it won't break anything
      echo "Something is wrong: INSIDE_EMACS is ${INSIDE_EMACS}" >&2
      ;;
  esac

  # finish shell setup for dumb now--the rest of the file will
  # be skipped
  return
fi

# Stuff for non-dumb, interactive visual, shells goes here
setup_prompt
setup_keybindings
etc
```

We don't reset `TERM` to a different value inside the case statement because `dumb` is exactly what it should be.

Note that above, in the `(tramp)` section of the case statement, you *could* do what you mentioned in your question—set `TERM` to something else just for TRAMP—but that would be a bad idea, since Emacs actually reads and acts on responses it gets from TRAMP shells, and the line noise would be an even bigger problem. TRAMP can do some really amazing things, but only when the shell output it's reading is in the format TRAMP expects.

(One final thing: using the code as above, with the `INSIDE_EMACS` checks nested instead the `dumb` terminal check, we don't have a single place to put code to be run in all Emacs-spawned shells regardless of type, including `M-x ansi-term` and its ilk. You could write a separate statement for that in your shell config... but that's exactly what `~/.emacs.d/init_${SHELLNAME}.sh` is for, so probably a better choice if you need this for some reason.)

Comment: Tomas, I just realized your question wasn't from a couple weeks ago but rather a year ago—you'd think by March I'd know it's 2019 and not 2018!—but I hope the answer is still useful enough (to others even if not to you) to consider it!

Comment: It's a really good and thorough answer.  I'm sure people will find it useful.